# Is there a way in Visual C# to get the maximum of two number?

Tags: c#

Is there a function like this in Visual C#?

```
int max(int a, int b)
{
if(a > b) return a;
return b;
}
```

Comment: everyone scramble!

Comment: -1 at some point you are going to have to start reading beginner books, because your questions are beyond trivial.

Comment: You might also want to consider the conditional operator to make a simpler statement without pushing a frame on the call stack: int max = a > b ? a : b;

Comment: Although this is an simple question, there's no need to pile on.  I've been doing .NET for several years and have never known Math.Max() existed.

Comment: Then again IMHO piling on isn't bad for future reference when others will come to view all context around questions. Somebody might find related bits and pieces useful. It's intended for everyone so a comment made isn't indirectly commenting on your experience level. The type of question posted reflects most on the author's experience level.

Comment: Google for functions is invaluable. When searching "C# math absolute function" every result on the first page reveals the Math.Abs method in the .NET Framework.
http://www.google.ca/search?q=C%23+math+absolute+function

Comment: But the point is that even experienced people don't know so it's a good question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
int max = Math.Max(a,b);
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you want to use the System.Math.Max method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx

```
int result = Math.Max(a, b);
```

There are various overloads to this, including one that takes two Int32 values (which looks like the one you're after).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Try Math.Max()